# Erro ao carregar imagem no aplicativo por requisição Json

Tags: java, android, json, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que captura imagens manda pro servidor, o servidor salva no banco, e quando o usuário quiser, ele pode fazer o download dessas fotos novamente em seu celular.

Até a parte de salvar no banco tudo bem. O problema é na conversão da URL String do banco para arquivo de imagem.

Estou usando o spring framework para desenvolver a API.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class Services {

@Autowired
private PacienteRepository pr;

@GetMapping("/pacientes")
public List<Paciente> listaPaciente() {
    return pr.findAll();
}
}
```

Aplicação mobile:

```
public static final String TAG = "LOG";
public static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/pacientes";
private List<Paciente> pacientes;
private ListView lvPalheta;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ImageView iv_capa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_galery );
    lvPalheta = findViewById(R.id.listview_pacientes);
    iv_capa = findViewById(R.id.tv_qtd);
    listarPacientes();
}
protected void listarPacientes() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Galery.this, "Aguarde um momento", "Carregando pedidos ...", true, false);
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type usuariosListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Paciente>>(){}.getType();
            pacientes = gson.fromJson(response, usuariosListType);
            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter( getApplicationContext(), pacientes);
            lvPalheta.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            lvPalheta.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                }
            });



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText( Galery.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }){

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Paciente> pacientes;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Paciente> pacientes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pacientes = pacientes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pacientes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return pacientes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_view_pacientes, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.person);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        iv_capa.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);     
        return v;
    }

}
```

Na saída diz que a conversão esta retornando um Bitmap nulo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]